# How come Swift authorizes under the hood, while Java does not?

Tags: java, oauth, access-token

In Swift I can programmatically log into OkCupid.com/login by simply  making the post request &username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&okc_api=1. This gets me my account's home page with access token. From there I can do anything I'd normally do in a browser.

When using Java, however, I used to be able to do the same thing up until about 6 months ago (Jan '16). Now after POSTING, I receive a session cookie, but instead of being redirected to .../home, I'm taken to a page with a JSON dictionary that holds my userid and oauth_accesstoken.

Assuming that my inability to login is due to OkCupid implementing oauth authorization, how can I with Java programmatically login?

```
{"actionable" : false, "status" : 0, "oauth_accesstoken" : "ATOKEN", "userid" : "MYUSERID", "status_str" : "Sorry, Staff Robot had a meltdown\u2014check back later", "screenname" : "MYSCREENNAME", "thumbnail" : "MYTHUMBNAIL", "show_alist_box" : null}
```

Comment: Check your headers. Do all of your request headers such as `User-Agent`, `Accept`, `Content-Type`, etc identical on the two different requests?

Comment: @CollinD your suggestion is moot now. Coincidentally I'm unable to login with swift either. Now I need for sure to know how to use the oauth token I'm being given. Any ideas?

Comment: Check their API docs probly your best bet.

Comment: I've scoured the web specifically looking for their Ali docs. Any ideas? Also I'm getting a 302 status for redirect when I check the browsers dev tool. I'm assuming the redirect is a callback using the oauth token??